# Firebase messaging iOS : usersInfo is empty or I never get the notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I follow the rules from the Google Firebase for configuring my iOS app. When I give to the Firebase Console a Device ID (token) which has never been used, the notification is caught by my app, but the userInfo is empty:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)") /* HERE */

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
}
```

On the line with the `/* HERE */` comment, the app crashes because userInfo is `nil`.

When I try again another notification from the Firebase console, the notification is not caught and nothing appends (I have a breakpoint in the reception notification function).

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the Firebase token that is generated and not the device token that made this mistake.  You will need to put this in your code to get the token you need:

```
print(FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token())
```

I put this inside of my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {}
```